# Mediawiki api login doesn't accept token

Tags: php, api, mediawiki

I'm trying to authenticate to the mediawiki api, but it doesn't accept the login token I requested. When I request (via POST) the token like this `action=query&meta=tokens&type=login&format=json` it returns me a a token, for example

```
batchcomplete:
query: {
    tokens: {
        logintoken: af69aa46ef0e505dca1b4b0ea696a55259258b4f+\
    }
}
```

But when I now try to authenticate with `action=login&lgname=user&lgpassword=password&lgtoken=af69aa46ef0e505dca1b4b0ea696a55259258b4f%2B%5C&format=json` I only getting this message back

```
warnings: {
    main: {
        *: Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes. Use [Special:ApiFeatureUsage]] to see usage of deprecated features by your application.
    }
    login: {
        *: Fetching a token via "action=login" is deprecated. Use "action=query&meta=tokens&type=login" instead.
    }
}
login: {
    result: NeedToken
    token: a26aa15ecc99c421db73b86e7581497959258b4f+\
}
```

It seems like it's not recognizing the token. I'm using a bot password to login.

Thanks for your help

Simon

Comment: You need to issue the requests in the same session.

Comment: How can I use sessions in a php script? :/

Comment: Depends on what you use for making web requests. With curl, you need to use the cookie jar + cookie file options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tgr's comment solved my question:

> You need to issue the requests in the same session.

How can I use sessions in a php script?

> Depends on what you use for making web requests. With curl, you need to use the cookie jar + cookie file options.